# Need to remove or customize pagination arrows from angular mat-paginator

Tags: html, css, angular, angular6

I actually need to remove the arrows present at angular mat-paginator because i need custom design. Can also workaround if the styling of these arrow can be changed. The link to mat-paginator is below.

https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview

[The arrows which i need to remove are shown in following picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suqsU.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do it with custom CSS, by overwriting this class <svg class="mat-paginator-icon"></svg>

Comment: tried overiting this class "mat-paginator-icon" but nothing happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite css class `mat-paginator-icon`

ex:

```
/deep/ .mat-icon-buton{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

> Do not forget to append `/deep/` before overwriting any material class.

Demo is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-pagination-123456

Note : Better would be to overwrite the css by material theme https://material.angular.io/guide/theming.

Comment: 1. What is /deep/?

Comment: The original intent of `/deep/` was to provide a way to handle exceptional cases of when the scoping boundary is in the way of an occasional practical need to tweak styling from outside of the scope or globally.

Comment: Also i tried it and it is not working. it only works when i do inspect element on chrome which is temporary.

Comment: Isn't `/deep/` deprecated? Chrome lists it as a removed feature [here](https://www.chromestatus.com/features#milestone%3D63).

Comment: @Zohaib - add `!important;` and ensure that there is space between `/deep/` and `class name`.

Comment: It worked i wasnot using . (dot) before mat-paginator-icon   Thanks for help.

Comment: Instead of using .mat-paginator-icon I am now using .mat-icon-buton and it is completely gone the way i wanted it. By using .mat-paginator-icon only the icon was gone but an invisible button was still there.

Comment: Done :). Again Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Please try below CSS code.

```
  .mat-paginator-navigation-previous {
        display: none !important;
    }

.mat-paginator-navigation-next {
            display: none !important;
        }
```

(or)

```
  .mat-paginator-navigation-previous {
       opacity: 0 !important;
       width: 0;
       height: 0;
   }

   .mat-paginator-navigation-next {
      opacity: 0 !important;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the classes to style the pager to your liking:

- mat-paginator-navigation-first (1)
- mat-paginator-navigation-previous (2)
- mat-paginator-navigation-next (3)
- mat-paginator-navigation-last (4)
- mat-paginator-range-label (5)
- mat-paginator-range-actions (6)
- mat-paginator-page-size-select (7)
- mat-paginator-page-size-label (8)
- mat-paginator-page-size (9)

[image]

In my case I wanted to leave only the dropdown (9), so I hide the rest with a display: none:

```
 .mat-paginator-range-actions {
            display: none !important;
  }
```

Result:
[image]